# Connection aborted, RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response') after 300k requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I try to get data through an API.
To achieve that, I created a multiprocessing pool to parallelize my calls and be more efficient. I run the pool with 6 processes (it's my limit to avoid going further than the 5 calls/seconds limit on the API)

The first 300k calls are running fine, but after a dozen hours of running, I always get the same error :

`('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`

The error is not catched by that piece of code, and therefor, make my run crash :

```py
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {bearer_token}".format(bearer_token=bearer_token)}

try:
        r = requests.get(url=GET_STUFF, headers=headers)

except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, ConnectionResetError):
        
        return {}
```

I'm not sure to understand why such an error happens here. After sometimes 15 hours of running fine. Is it caused by my internet connection or I am getting banned ?

Is it safe to "just catch" the exception and treat it like an empty response ? (empty response are properly handled in my code so it's not a problem)

PS : here is the code I use to run the multiprocessing pool :

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6) as pool:
            results = pool.starmap(get_job_offers, parameters)
    except Exception as e:
        telegram_bot_sendtext('Error Raised')
        logging.error(e)
```

Comment: The error usually means the server is closing the request without completing it. Could be that you are being ratelimited.

Comment: That's weird because there is no other limit than the 5 calls / sec and even if I cross the line, it just returns an empty json (which is properly handled) :/